# Custom incremental update in Windows

Tags: networking, windows-7, update

Our client has 100+ computer in the network and they are switching to Windows 7 next month.

Our software is based on SQL 2008 and .NET 1.1 binaries. They requirement is to create an **incremental auto-update solution to avoid Windows Update** and has the possibility to react fast and efficient for new security updates (ie. SQL Server 2008 R2 CU7).

I'm sure that the community has more than one great solution for that but I'm not able to found it.

Our **idea** is this:

- A **windows service runs as Local admin** in the background
- It **watches a network drive**, if there is a new version (a new folder, lets say) it will run the content, possibly an PowerShell file
- If an older notebook comes into play, it must be **upgraded from the last known update**

For **example** the update directory is that:

```
Directory1
  SQL 2k8 update 1
Dircetory2
  Our software update 1
Directory3
  SQL 2k8 update 2
Dircetory4
  SQL 2k8 update 4
```

After every successful update the client saves the last version (for example *"I'm up-to-date to Directory4"*).

This is just an idea any others are welcome!

Comment: Why is Windows Update not an option?

Comment: This is a big company, Windows Update works not the "common" way. Secondly we have to publish our software too and it would be nice to do both with the same solution.

Comment: You can use Windows Update via WSUS servers and publish your own updates into the WSUS servers.  WSUS includes the ability to approve/deny updates so only the updates which you want pushed out are pushed out.

Comment: WSUS is restricted and owned by the global IT in India. It's simply not enough fast is emergency cases.

Comment: There's a variety of application deployment tools available, including Active Directory.  Reinventing the wheel just doesn't seam like a cost effective solution considering the options which are already available.  If the current architecture doesn't work fixing the architecture will probably be the best bet.

Comment: I agree. Can you write me few tool names? Thank you.

Comment: Here's an article (which is a little old) which lists several. http://www.networkworld.com/reviews/2003/0303patchrev.html  A quick Google search will find you several.